# How do I get data from a nested dict?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Hello I'm trying to get specific data out an API call from a website. This is the data I'm receiving

This is the data I'm recieving

```
{'type': 'NonStockItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '1', 'description': 'Ikke lagerførte varer høy sats'}
{'type': 'NonStockItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '2', 'description': 'Ikke lagerførte varer middels sats'}
{'type': 'NonStockItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '3', 'description': 'Ikke lagerførte varer lav sats'}
{'type': 'NonStockItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '4', 'description': 'Ikke lagerførte varer avgiftsfri'}
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': False, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}], 'id': '5', 'description': 'Lagerførte varer høy sats'}
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '6', 'description': 'Lagerførte varer middels sats'}
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '7', 'description': 'Lagerførte varer avgiftsfri'}
{'type': 'LaborItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '8', 'description': 'Tjenester (prosjekt)'}
{'type': 'ExpenseItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '9', 'description': 'Utgifter (Reise)'}
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}], 'id': 'ONLINE', 'description': 'Online'}
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': False, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}, {'attributeId': 'WEB2', 'description': 'tilgjengelighet i nettbutikk', 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Combo', 'details': [{'id': 'Ikke Inne', 'description': 'Produktet er utsolgt.'}, {'id': 'Inne', 'description': 'tilgjengelig i nettbutikk'}]}], 'id': 'WEB', 'description': 'Tilgjengelig på nettbutikk.'}
```

This is the object fields

```
[
          {
            "type": "NonStockItem",
            "attributes": [
              {
                "attributeId": "string",
                "description": "string",
                "sortOrder": 0,
                "required": true,
                "attributeType": "Text"
    }
]
```

this is my code

```
if response.status_code == 200:
itemClass = json.loads(response.text)

for item in itemClass:
      print(item["type"])
      print(item["description"])
      print(item["attributes"])
```

What I'm trying to do is to get only the attributes with an existing attributeId. I'm a bit stuck because the data inside the attributes array is a dict, how can I get the key values?

Current output:

```
    NonStockItem
Ikke lagerførte varer høy sats
[]
NonStockItem
Ikke lagerførte varer middels sats
[]
NonStockItem
Ikke lagerførte varer lav sats
[]
NonStockItem
Ikke lagerførte varer avgiftsfri
[]
FinishedGoodItem
Lagerførte varer høy sats
[{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': False, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}]
FinishedGoodItem
Lagerførte varer middels sats
[]
FinishedGoodItem
Lagerførte varer avgiftsfri
[]
LaborItem
Tjenester (prosjekt)
[]
ExpenseItem
Utgifter (Reise)
[]
FinishedGoodItem
Online
[{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}]
FinishedGoodItem
Tilgjengelig på nettbutikk.
[{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': False, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}, {'attributeId': 'WEB2', 'description': 'tilgjengelighet i nettbutikk', 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Combo', 'details': [{'id': 'Ikke Inne', 'description': 'Produktet er utsolgt.'}, {'id': 'Inne', 'description': 'tilgjengelig i nettbutikk'}]}]
```

> 

I only want the types which contain an attributeId

Comment: Could you provide us with a more detailed data sample.

Comment: @Thekingis007 I updated the quesiton now, expected output is only Items that contains attributeId, I don't want the empty arrays

Comment: I meant your input not output but I hope my solution answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the list you are working on is accessible using `lst[0]['attributes']`.

Try the following, which uses list comprehension:

```py
lst = [
        {
            "type": "NonStockItem",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attributeId": "string",
                    "description": "string",
                    "sortOrder": 0,
                    "required": True,
                    "attributeType": "Text"
                    },
                {
                    # Note that it does not have attributeId
                    "description": "string",
                    "sortOrder": 0,
                    "required": True,
                    "attributeType": "Text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

attrs = lst[0]['attributes']
output = [d for d in attrs if 'attributeId' in d]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'attributeId': 'string', 'description': 'string', 'sortOrder': 0, 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Text'}]
```

Note that the output has only one element; in the input example I gave, the second dict does not have `attributeId`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I could think considering your data sample and output is to verify if `item["attributes"]` has values inside or no:

Code:

```
itemclass = [{'type': 'NonStockItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '1', 'description': 'Ikke lagerførte varer høy sats'},
{'type': 'NonStockItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '2', 'description': 'Ikke lagerførte varer middels sats'},
{'type': 'NonStockItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '3', 'description': 'Ikke lagerførte varer lav sats'},
{'type': 'NonStockItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '4', 'description': 'Ikke lagerførte varer avgiftsfri'},
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': False, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}], 'id': '5', 'description': 'Lagerførte varer høy sats'},
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '6', 'description': 'Lagerførte varer middels sats'},
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '7', 'description': 'Lagerførte varer avgiftsfri'},
{'type': 'LaborItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '8', 'description': 'Tjenester (prosjekt)'},
{'type': 'ExpenseItem', 'attributes': [], 'id': '9', 'description': 'Utgifter (Reise)'},
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}], 'id': 'ONLINE', 'description': 'Online'},
{'type': 'FinishedGoodItem', 'attributes': [{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': False, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}, {'attributeId': 'WEB2', 'description': 'tilgjengelighet i nettbutikk', 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Combo', 'details': [{'id': 'Ikke Inne', 'description': 'Produktet er utsolgt.'}, {'id': 'Inne', 'description': 'tilgjengelig i nettbutikk'}]}], 'id': 'WEB', 'description': 'Tilgjengelig på nettbutikk.'}]

for item in itemclass:
    if item["attributes"]:
        print(item["type"])
        print(item["description"])
        print(item["attributes"])
```

Output:

```
FinishedGoodItem
Lagerførte varer høy sats
[{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': False, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}]
FinishedGoodItem
Online
[{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}]
FinishedGoodItem
Tilgjengelig på nettbutikk.
[{'attributeId': 'NETTBUTIKK', 'description': 'WEB', 'required': False, 'attributeType': 'Text', 'details': []}, {'attributeId': 'WEB2', 'description': 'tilgjengelighet i nettbutikk', 'required': True, 'attributeType': 'Combo', 'details': [{'id': 'Ikke Inne', 'description': 'Produktet er utsolgt.'}, {'id': 'Inne', 'description': 'tilgjengelig i nettbutikk'}]}]
```

Comment: Is there any way to access the fields inside attributes and filter/sort on them?

Comment: @SuzdarIbrahim I've edited my solution check it out.

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting this error msg: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @SuzdarIbrahim That's why I asked for a sample input data, could you please provide it in your question?

Comment: I've updated it now

Comment: @SuzdarIbrahim Clearly you're checking whether `item["attributes"]` has values inside or no.

Comment: I've edited your example, take a look

Answer (score 0):

Pandas json_normalize could be used for this as well:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

response = '''[
    {
        "type": "NonStockItem",
        "attributes": [
        {
            "attributeId": "string1",
            "description": "string",
            "sortOrder": 0,
            "required": true,
            "attributeType": "Text"
        },
         {
            "attributeId": "string2",
            "description": "string",
            "sortOrder": 0,
            "required": true,
            "attributeType": "Text"
        }]
    },
    {
        "type": "NonStockItem",
        "attributes":[]
    },
    {
        "type": "NonStockItem",
        "attributes": [
        {
            "attributeId": "string3",
            "description": "string",
            "sortOrder": 0,
            "required": true,
            "attributeType": "Text"
        },
         {
            "attributeId": "string4",
            "description": "string",
            "sortOrder": 0,
            "required": true,
            "attributeType": "Text"
        }]
    }    
    ]
'''
itemClass = json.loads(response)
```

```
print(pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(x["attributes"]) for x in itemClass], 
    ignore_index=True))
```

```
  attributeId description  sortOrder  required attributeType
0     string1      string          0      True          Text
1     string2      string          0      True          Text
2     string3      string          0      True          Text
3     string4      string          0      True          Text
```